# Как расставить слова на полотне в определенной форме

Tags: java

Могу ли я используя java добиться такой расстановки слов? Если да, то порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, технологии и библиотеки для этого. Спасибо заранее за ответ.
Вот пример. Слова расположены в виде восклицательного знака.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]